# Java Byte to Float

Tags: java, floating-point, byte

I reveive 2 Byte and I want to represent them as `float`. 
I know about the Method

```
float f = ByteBuffer.wrap(weight).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getFloat();
```

But this Method only worky with 4 byte arrays.
Is there a way to this for only 2 Byte? I thought about adding two 0 Byte to the array weight to get 4 Byte in the array but the result is far from what I am expecting.

```
byte[] Data = characteristic.getValue();
byte[] weight = new byte[4];
weight[3] = Data[2];
weight[2] = Data[1];
weight[1] = 0;
weight[0] = 0;
float f = ByteBuffer.wrap(weight).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getFloat();
```

Additionally I have to swap the two bytes I am receiving, that's why I change their positions. I also tried

```
    weight[0] = Data[2];
    weight[1] = Data[1];
    weight[2] = 0;
    weight[3] = 0;
```

But it also does not fit.
Thx

Comment: *but the result is far from what I am expecting* - What are you expecting and what's happening instead?

Comment: And what do you know about floating-point representation?

Comment: I am connected to a ble device and I know the float value that I will receive of it.

Comment: @medTech You didn't answer my question. Please update your post with the input values, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Ok for example
I expect the float value 16,5 and I receive the bytes 114 and 6. And I know that I have to swap them and than I can represent them as the desired output

Comment: Are you sure that the source is correctly converting the floating point number into byte-representation. Coz byte-representation of a floating point can be tricky

Comment: I am assuming you are using the Half-precision floating-point format (binary16 or IEEE 754-2008)?
In that case you have 1 bit sign, 5 bit exponent and 10 bit fraction.
With that knowledge all you need to do is calculate your float bitwise.